# Can't upload files with IE11 - does not support binary blobs

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the following script to upload files,

```
function upload_file(id, index)
{     
    var input = document.getElementById('FILE_INPUT_' + index);
    var parentId = id;            
    var filesToUpload = input.files;

    for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();     

        // Keep a reference to the File in the FileReader so it can be accessed in callbacks
        reader.file = f; 

        reader.onerror = function(e) 
        {
            switch(e.target.error.code) 
            {
                case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    alert('File Not Found!');
                    break;
                case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                    alert('File is not readable');
                    break;
                case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                    break; // noop
                default:
                    alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
            };
        };     

        reader.onabort = function(e) 
        {
            alert('File read cancelled');
        };

        reader.onload = function(e) 
        {
            var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment");
            att.Name = this.file.name;
            att.ContentType = this.file.type;
            att.ParentId = parentId;

            att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();

            sforce.connection.create([att],
            {
                onSuccess : function(result, source) 
                {
                    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                    {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log("answer id " + answer_id);
                        console.log("new attachment created with id " + result[0].id);
                        refresh_page();
                        //jQuery('.file_input').val('');

                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        console.log('failure');
                        console.log("answer id " + answer_id);
                        console.log("failed to create attachment " + result[0]);
                        //jQuery('.file_input').val('');
                    }
                }, 
                onFailure : function(error, source) 
                {
                    console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
                }
            });
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but I get the following error in IE 11,

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'readAsBinaryString'
```

So it looks like IE does not support binary blobs, is there any work around this??

Thanks

Comment: That's quite specific to javascript and IE, and not really specific to salesforce or related technologies. On a next occation it may be best to post questions like this on stackoverflow.com, our "parent" site which deals with a broader range of languanges and technologies. It has more experts on non salesforce related topics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to make it work by switching to `readAsArrayBuffer` and then using the following in your `onload` callback to build the binary String.

```
var binary = "";
var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
var length = bytes.byteLength;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
}

att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(binary)).toString();
```

Comment: Once again Alex, thanks a million! Works perfectly!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391207/javascript-readasbinarystring-function-on-e11 for non salesforce solution